# Laravel set and detect enviroment using .env file

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on `Laravel 4.2.`

I've three environments - `Local` i.e. my `localhost` on WAMP, `dev` i.e. `development` environment on Ubuntu digital ocean and `production` - i.e. `Production` environment on Ubuntu Amazon.

Now, each time I deploy the code on each environment, I am forced to manually setup host name, database name, user and password.

I go through the `Laravel` documentation as well as some searching and finally I've created 3 directories inside `app/config/` directory namely - `local`, `dev` and `production`. I've placed `database.php` inside each directory with the said database connection settings.

Now I've created a `evn.local.php` file in the `root` directory for local environment as below :

```
<?php 

return [

    'STRIPE_SECRET' => 'my-secrete-test-stripe-key',
    'APP_ENV'=>'local'
];
```

And also have changed `$app->detectEnvironment` function of `\bootstrap\start.php` as :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
      return getenv('APP_ENV') ?   : 'local';
});
```

It is working fine for local but I am not sure will it work for `dev` and `production` or not.

Also, in `App/Config/Services.php` I've placed code :

```
'stripe' => array(
        'model'  => 'User',
        'secret' => $_ENV['STRIPE_SECRET'],
)
```

and If I use like

```
Config::get('services.stripe.secret')
```

it is giving me the secrete key I've placed in `evn.local.php` but if I use the same to get the environment in `\bootstrap\start.php` as :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
     return $_ENV['APP_ENV'];
});
```

it is not working. Gives error `Undefined index: APP_ENV`.

Can anyone guide me what am I missing? Or am I handling it wrong way?

Comment: I know Laravel 5 handles environment variables using a .env file; is there any way for you to move away from 4.2? I haven't worked with 4.2 in a while, but I remember the environment/config being a pain sometimes.

Comment: You can't use `$_ENV` in your start.php because the environment hasn't been detected yet. `$_ENV` gets populated AFTER the detect environment call. You need to use a different method for detecting the environment. (checking machine name, IP address.. etc.)